# Count the occurrence of a word in a table in SQL Server database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I need to count the occurrence of a word in a SQL Server table `news1` in a column `title`.

The code returns zero value:

```
sql = "SELECT SUM((LEN(title) - LEN(REPLACE(title, '" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "', '')))/LEN('" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "')) FROM news1"
comm = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
conn.Open()
Dim count21 As Integer = comm.ExecuteScalar()
conn.Close()
MsgBox (count21)
```

Comment: Why not just `select count(*) from news1 where title like '%@searchText%'` ? Also this is VB.NET (Well really, the question is about `SQL`), not C#.

Comment: I need to count all words in every row

Answer (score 1):

To count the occurrence of character in a string query should be something like

```
Len('sttring') - Len(Replace('sttring', 't', '')) -- Result : 2
```

So your query should be something like

```
SELECT Sum(( Len(title) - Len(Replace(title, '" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "', ''))) / 
                  Cast(Len('" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "') AS NUMERIC(10, 1))) 
FROM   news1
```

To avoid integer division convert either numerator or denominator to decimal value.

```
SELECT Sum(( Len(title) - Len(Replace(title, '" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "', '')) ) / cast(Len('" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "') as numeric(10,1))
FROM   news1
```

Also the reason why you got `0` as result is due to **integer division** which is not needed in your case

**Example:**

consider `(LEN(title) - LEN(REPLACE(title, '" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "', '')))` returns `3` and `LEN('" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "'))` returns `10` then

```
select 3/10 -- Result 0
```

Comment: It also returns zero value :)

Comment: What I need is like this example :
title1=" My name is Ali and my father name also Ali"
title2="Ali is my name"
title3="Where is Ali"

count of "Ali"=4

Comment: Do you want decimal part in result

Comment: please try to help me as you can
I need to calculate the term frequency of any word in the title column. Maybe my code is not correct so try to guide me :) thanks

Comment: I got this error:
Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'.

Comment: @AliMohammed - check now updated. There was a misplaced `)`.